# Storing Pictures To mysql Using Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm trying to store some upload pictures to my database using laravel. Everything goes well, everything got stored, but for the file, they keep storing a bin file of 38B, I've tried reading it to .Txt files and it has a path to /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpUzMXbn.
Here is my function code :

```
Route::post('/FruitCreate',function(Request $request){
$fruit = new fruit;
$fruit->name = $request->name;
$fruit->price = $request->price;
$fruit->picture = $request->image;
$fruit->save();
return redirect('FruitsChangingPricePanel');
```

My form blade :

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="{{ url('FruitCreate') }}" >
{{ csrf_field() }}
<input type="text" name='name'>
<input type="text" name='price'>
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000000" />
<input type="file" name='image'>
<button type='submit'> submit </button>
```

thank u For Your Help !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do may be something like that:

`$file = $request->file('image');`
`$imageContent = $file->openFile()->fread($file->getSize())`; 
`$fruit = new fruit; $fruit>picture = $imageContent; $fruit>save();`

Note: Your column type must be Blob

Answer (score 0):

because you are trying to save directly bin. 
try this one

```
         $file = Input::file('file');

        $destinationPath = public_path(). '/uploads/';
        $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();

        $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);

        echo  $filename;
        //echo '<img src="uploads/'. $filename . '"/>';

        $user = ImageTest::create([
            'filename' => $filename,
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should get your image and then store it to `public/uploads/fruits` folder.And after that, you are saving the path to your picture to DB.

```
$fruit = new fruit;
$fruit->name = $request->name;
$fruit->price = $request->price;

if ($request->has('image')) {
   if (!file_exists(public_path('uploads/fruits/'))) {
       mkdir(public_path('uploads/fruits/'));
   }
   if (!file_exists(public_path('uploads/fruits/' . date('FY') . '/'))) {
       mkdir(public_path('uploads/fruits/' . date('FY') . '/'));
   }
    $image = $request->file('image');
    $filename = public_path('uploads').'/fruits/' . date('FY') . '/' . str_random() . '.' . $image->guessExtension();
    \Image::make($image->getRealPath())->encode('jpg')->resize(220, 220)->put($filename);

    $fruit->picture = $filename;
}

$fruit->save();
```